# How to assign rawValue of enum to variable with ObjectMapper?

Tags: swift, alamofire, objectmapper

Hello I am using [Object Mapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) with Alamofire in Swift and I am trying to map enum raw value to real Enum.

Here is my enum and also the code I am trying to use in function *mapping*. Can you please help me what to pass as argument to EnumTransform or how to modify the code? I know I can read the value as string and the use LevelType(rawValue: stringValue).

Thanks in advance.

```
enum LevelType : String {
    case NEW = "NEW"
    case UPDATE = "UPDATE"
}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    typeEnum <- (map[“type”], EnumTransformable(???) )
}
```

Comment: It is not required to write case NEW = "NEW". "NEW" will be value by default(the same as name of case). enum LevelType : String {
    case NEW,UPDATE} will be the same

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You don't have to pass an argument at all. All you have to do is to specify enum type as generic argument and ObjectMapper will take care for all enum initialization procedures.

```
 typeEnum <- (map["type"],EnumTransform<LevelType>())
```

Comment: I did the same as suggested here but i get the error saying -- Binary operator <- cannot be applied to string and (map , enumTranform<LevelType>())

Comment: You need to declare enum type, var typeEnum: LevelType!

Answer (score 4):

Just doing a straight map worked fine for me as long as my enum was declared to be of type String.

```
typeEnum <- map["type"]
```